# Rails: How to render pages using AJAX and maintain DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a calendar page that shows a person's routine for an entire month. At the top, I have button for the previous and next months. When those are clicked, I make an AJAX call to the change_date action which updates the dates and finds the new routines. When the change_date.js.erb is called, do I have to write the code to change the content for everyday's actions again? This seems to be violating DRY.
Is there any way I can reuse the partials I used to populate the page on initial load to repopulate the page with the new values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, there is. Simply use `render` as you did in your html templates. Usually a setup that supports ajax and regular calls looks something like this (of course names are wildly guessed):

```
# controller
def change_date
  @dates = Date.where(:date => params[:date])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end

# change_date.html.erb
<ul id="calendar">
  <%= render @dates %>
</ul>

# change_date.js.erb
$("#calendar").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @dates) %>");

# _date.html.erb
<li><%= date.date %></li>
```

So you see, you can simply use the same partial on both scenarios.

And just another suggestion: Depending on your setup it may be more restful to not have another method in the controller, but to use the `show` method which operates depending on a query param in this case...

Comment: Indeed. Thank you, I do not have much experience with JQuery but it seems the .html() method can replace the older content as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would load the person's routine via ajax when the page is first loaded as well.

I would encapsulate it in a js function and call that function when the page is first loaded and everytime the month is changed.

Comment: The disadvantage may be, that if someone has JavaScript turned off or is prohibited to have it turned on, it wouldn't load at all...

Comment: I agree. Not necessarily with the metaphor, but I agree :-) Although you'd be surprised how many intranets, etc. are blocked for using js...